# how to override front page node tpl - drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How to override drupal front page node.tpl file ? I tried various

```
   node--front.tpl.php
   page--node--front.tpl.php
   page--front--node.tpl.php
```

but its not working.

What will be the file name to override home page node ? (I am working in drupal 7)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add this function to theme template.php

```
   function customethemename_preprocess_node ( &$vars ) {

        if ($vars["is_front"]) {
           $vars["theme_hook_suggestions"][] = "node__front";
        }  
    }
```

Then you can page page--front.tpl.php

It will solve the problem

Answer (score 6):

It should be `page--front.tpl.php`

Also, be sure that you have the precursors in the hierarchy for your theme (e.g. `page.tpl.php`)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend solving this by setting a specific node of content to be the front page.

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/drupal-7/homepage/change-front-page

Then I would use a specific node ID template.

`node--[insert id here].tpl.php`  i.e. `node--1.tpl.php`

You need to do two things before this will work:

1. Make sure you have a copy of the original node.tpl.php file in your theme folder (the overridden template file will not be picked up otherwise).
2. Clear Drupal's cache

Answer (score 0):

No need to develop manually a front page, just creaate a frontpage by views or another and set it the as the front page in :

```
www.yoursite.com/?q=admin/config/site-information
```

Answer (score 0):

Following steps resolved the issue for me to create custom front page in Drupal 7.

1. Create a file: page--front.tpl.php. Notice two hyphens instead of
   one.
2. Clear the cache: Configuration >> Development >> Performance>>
   Clear all caches

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is using frontpage nid

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_node ( &$vars ) {
list(, $frontpage_nid) = explode('/', drupal_get_normal_path(variable_get('site_frontpage', 'node')));

  if ($vars['node']->nid == $frontpage_nid) {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = "node__frontpage";
  } 
}
```

Because

```
if ($vars["is_front"]) {
    $vars["theme_hook_suggestions"][] = "node__front";
}
```

add the theme suggestion for all nodes in frontpage, not only for frontpage node